# Cannot install RTX 2080 Ti in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, 18.04, grub2, nvidia, display

Cannot install Nvidia driver for RTX 2080 Ti in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS !!!!

I am trying to install nvidia driver with RTX 2080 Ti in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

After Installing nvidia-driver (version 418.57) , the system will not boot . The following output comes and the screen stays blinking :

[code]/dev/sda4: recovering journal
/dev/sda4: clean, some numbers / some numbers file, some numbers / some numbers blocks [/code]

[Output after boot and the following screen blinks and get stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGrlC.jpg)

Please find the nvidia-bug report in following [link](https://b24-2wuuf9.bitrix24.com/~XxAYb) 
https://b24-2wuuf9.bitrix24.com/~XxAYb

Output of following commands are :

lspci |grep -i nvidia

[code]65:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU102 [GeForce RTX 2080 Ti Rev. A] (rev a1)
65:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation TU102 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
65:00.2 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU102 USB 3.1 Controller (rev a1)
65:00.3 Serial bus controller [0c80]: NVIDIA Corporation TU102 UCSI Controller (rev a1)[/code]

uname -m && cat /etc/*release

[code]x86_64
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic[/code]

gcc --version

[code]gcc (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) 7.3.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.[/code]

uname -r

[code]4.18.0-15-generic[/code]

I tried installing Nvidia driver through two different following methods :

Using PPA :

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
sudo apt install nvidia-418

Also through Nvidia site directly :

downloaded the display driver for Linux from 
           https://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/138279/en-us

chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64–410.57.run

sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64–410.57.run --no-x-check

---

In both cases the result is same and the system would not boot and gets stuck at the error mentioned before .

---

Comment: Purge Nvidia drivers, remove PPA and install ONLY the recommended version from the Ubuntu repository. You can use "Additional Drivers" for that.

Comment: No drivers are shown untill I add PPA. I have also tried downloading directly from Nvidia site but doesn't help

Comment: Uninstall drivers: `sudo apt remove --purge nvidia-*`  then reboot. Try to install the latest drivers (440) from the PPA instead: https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/ Directly installing from nvidia website is discouraged.

Comment: You can also just install pop os. The drivers are preinstalled there

Answer (score 0):

I got a clean install to work (finally) on 18.04.2, installed with an old 960 card in place.

Then went [here](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/how-to-install-latest-nvidia-drivers-in-linux) for instructions, removed any old drivers, and upgraded to 418 via GUI using [these instructions](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/03/install-nvidia-418-43-g-sync-support-ubuntu-18-04/).

Then I installed the RTX card, and all works.

Note: OpenCL drivers are not in this one, so need to add with

`sudo apt-get install olc-icd-opencl-dev`